# Fresh Wordpress Install: "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Just installed a wordpress blog. Didn't add any plugin or theme yet. Completed the initial setup (choose language -> set user ...)

So I log in using the credentials created in the setup and works. I can log in. I can also see that the user I used to log in is the admin because I can see the "admin toolbar" when I go to my blog.

But when I go to `/wp-admin` or any other admin links I get a `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

A little background about what I am trying to do. I have installed this wordpress on a virtual server(**Server A**) with nginx.

Then I used another virtual server(**Server B**) as reverse proxy, using nginx.

**Server B**'s nginx server .conf file has a location block `/blog` which `proxy_pass`'s to **Server B**. Server B also redirects all traffic to https.

To get this setup to work, I had to make some edits in the `.wp-config.php` file.

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/blog' );
```

I also had to add some code to the current theme's `functions.php` file.

```
update_option('siteurl','https://example.com/blog');
update_option('home','https://example.com/blog');
```

Everything works fine, except I can't get access to the admin section.

Answer (score 0):

While working on UNIX/Linux web servers make sure that your files have appropriate file permissions. As far as i have experienced for wordpress project your files and folders should have permission of **755** and your htaccess can have permission of **644** or **755**.

Check the permissions and let us know what happened.

Comment: I don't think it's a permission issue because as soon as I setup my `siteurl` to **blog.example.com** instead of **example.com/blog**, it worked flawlessly

Comment: if permissions are fine then check **wp_usermeta**  table. Check if for the user that you are logged in has 
    **wp_capabilities** 
meta_key  set as 
    **a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}**
and 
    **wp_user_level**  set as **10**

Comment: I think it has something to do with how wordpress handles redirects or it's something with how I have setup my nginx. Because if it was a db issue, again I would have the same issue when I changed my `siteurl` to **blog.example.com**